# Finding the overall average of nested lists in Scheme?

Tags: scheme

Hey guys, I'm using MIT Scheme and trying to write a procedure to find the average of all the numbers in a bunch of nested lists, for example:

```
(average-lists (list 1 2 (list 3 (list 4 5)) 6)))
```

Should return 3.5. I've played with the following code for days, and right now I've got it returning the sum, but not the average. Also, it is important that the values of the inner-most lists are calculated first, so no extracting all values and simply averaging them.

Here's what I have so far:

```
(define (average-lists data)
  (if (null? data)
      0.0
      (if (list? (car data))
            (+ (average-lists (car data)) (average-lists (cdr data)))
            (+ (car data) (average-lists (cdr data))))))
```

I've tried this approach, as well as trying to use `map` to map a lambda function to it recursively, and a few others, but I just can't find one.  I think I'm making thing harder than it should be.

I wrote the following in an effort to pursue some other paths as well, which you may find useful:

```
(define (list-num? x)    ;Checks to see if list only contains numbers
  (= (length (filter number? x)) (length x)))

(define (list-avg x)     ;Returns the average of a list of numbers
  (/ (accumulate + 0 x) (length x)))
```

Your help is really appreciated!  This problem has been a nightmare for me.  :)

Comment: "the values of the inner-most lists are calculated first" - why? Side-effects? In a functional program? Looks there is something odd going on there. By the way - why don't you first flatten the list in a manner where you evaluate the inner-most lists first, and calculate the average afterwards?

Comment: Please don't put closing parens on their own lines.  It's not Scheme style.

Comment: Please DON'T delete questions after they've been answered!  It leaves no context for future reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless the parameters require otherwise, you'll want to define a helper procedure that can calculate both the **sum** and the **count** of how many items are in each list.  Once you can average a single list, it's easy to adapt it to nested lists by checking to see if the `car` is a list.

This method will get you the average in one pass over the list, rather than the two or more passes that solutions that flatten the list or do the count and the sums in two separate passes.  You would have to get the sum and counts separately from the sublists to get the overall average, though (re. zinglon's comment below).

**Edit:**

One way to get both the sum and the count back is to pass it back in a pair:

```
(define sum-and-count  ; returns (sum . count)
  (lambda (ls) 
   (if (null? ls)
       (cons 0 0)
       (let ((r (sum-and-count (cdr ls))))
         (cons (+ (car ls) (car r))
               (add1 (cdr r)))))))
```

That procedure gets the sum and number of elements of a list.  Do what you did to your own `average-lists` to it to get it to examine deeply-nested lists.  Then you can get the average by doing `(/ (car result) (cdr result))`.

Or, you can write separate `deep-sum` and `deep-count` procedures, and then do `(/ (deep-sum ls) (deep-count ls))`, but that requires two passes over the list.

Comment: Note that to get the result he wants, he'd have to accumulate the (sum, count) values of sublists directly instead of calculating the average of sublists and accumulating them. Your answer seems to imply the latter, but the overall strategy is sound and it's only a minor change to get his desired result. +1

Comment: @zinglon Oops, was typing faster than I could read and comprehend.  You're absolutely right.

Comment: @enkrypt0r See my edit. Hopefully my code snippet is enough to show what I was getting at.

Answer (score 3):

```
(define (flatten mylist)
  (cond ((null? mylist) '())
        ((list? (car mylist)) (append (flatten (car mylist)) (flatten (cdr mylist))))
        (else (cons (car mylist) (flatten (cdr mylist))))))


(define (myavg mylist)
  (let ((flatlist (flatten mylist)))
    (/ (apply + flatlist) (length flatlist))))
```

The first function flattens the list. That is, it converts `'(1 2 (3 (4 5)) 6)` to `'(1 2 3 4 5 6)`
Then its just a matter of applying `+` to the flat list and doing the average.

> Reference for the first function:
>   http://www.dreamincode.net/code/snippet3229.htm